# Show/hide text boxes depending on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide/show text boxes when user click on check boxes. I already searched in stack overflow, but I didn't get the solution..

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobile_number" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
```

I want to give one check box name display contact info or not. If user click on yes I want to show these two fields. If user click no I want to hide these two fields.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are the checkboxes?

Comment: i want to give one checkbox display contact info or not..if user click on yes i want to show these two fields..if no i want to hide

Comment: That should not be a big issue try some code then.

Comment: bind a change event on checkboxes and then just toggle the target element on the basis of checked state: `$('.has-feedback').toggle($('#yes').is('checked'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function check(opt){
 if(opt == 'yes'){
    document.getElementById('email').style.display="";
    document.getElementById('mobile').style.display="";
    document.getElementById("no").checked=false;
 }
 else
 if(opt == 'no'){
     document.getElementById('email').style.display="none";
     document.getElementById('mobile').style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("yes").checked=false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input style="display:none;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input style="display:none;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobile_number" id="mobile" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  Yes : <input type="checkbox" onclick="check('yes');" id="yes" />
  No : <input type="checkbox" onclick="check('no');" id="no" />
```

Comment: it's working but in my code  class name  form-group is applied for another fields also..so when i click on button the first name and last names are hiding..

Comment: it's working..but i want to show when user opens page first time i want to hide these two text boxes..by lcicking on checkbox only i want to show ..

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this simple task by jQuery. Suppose you have checkbox with an id of contact-info you have to check that is checked with the help of :checked seudo class and display input type display none and display block.

```
if('#contact-info').is(":checked")){
   $('#email,#mobile').css("display","block");
}else{
   $('#email,#mobile').css("display","none");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check

```
$(function(){
    $('your checkbox id or name').prop(true/false);
    checkBoxOnchange();
});

function checkBoxOnchange() {
    if ($('your checkbox id or name').is(":checked")) {
        $("input[name='email']").show();
        $("input[name='mobile_number']").show();
    } else {
        $("input[name='email']").hide();
        $("input[name='mobile_number']").hide();
    }
}

and in ur checkbox on-change event call checkBoxOnchange()
```

Comment: yes as usual if u use jquery frame work include in your header and set initial visibility for inputs too..

Comment: i am working on codeigniter..which file i need to include and how to set initial visibility for inputs

Comment: it's working but..when user opens page first time i want to hide these two fields..by clicking on yes only it should show..